# Why does SNAT happen in POSTROUTING chain and DNAT in PREROUTING chain?

Tags: iptables, netfilter

Why does `SNAT`(modifies source IP and/or ports) happen in `nat` table `POSTROUTING` chain, i.e after routing? And why does `DNAT`(modifies destination IP ant/or ports) happen in `PREROUTING` chain? I guess latter is because there might be multiple NICs in PC with different private networks and PC does not know how to route packet if destination IP address is still publickly routable address? However, for `SNAT` I can not see a reason why this couldn't take place in `PREROUTING`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually the main criterion for SNAT is "traffic that's going out a given interface" (i.e. `-o eth0`). What interface a packet will go out is determined by routing, so to apply that criterion you need to run it in a `POSTROUTING` context.

DNAT rewrites the destination address of a packet, meaning it can affect where a packet goes to — for example, a packet that looks like it's destined for the gateway could end up being rewritten to go to a machine on the network instead. Since you want the routing to be able to take that rewritten destination into account when it makes its decision, so that the packet actually goes where it needs to, DNAT should run in a `PREROUTING` context.

Comment: Indeed, good points! So `SNAT` couldn't happen in `PREROUTING` chain because this would mean that all the packets get `SNAT` -ed while actually this would be desired only for example for Internet facing interface? And `DNAT` needs to happen in `PREROUTING` because destination IP is changed and thus it needs to happen before routing decision in order to be routed via correct (LAN-facing) interface?

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure anything coming from the local machine never goes through the `PREROUTING` table, as seen [in this awesome ASCII figure](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/NAT-HOWTO-5.html).

Comment: Yes, but is this important? I mean you would do `DNAT` only in case the PC acts as a router and at least one of the LAN networks use private IP addresses.

Comment: It's important because you asked why you can't do `SNAT` in `prerouting` and I answered - packets whose source is the local machine never visit that table. That's why it can't.

Comment: Ok, but in which scenario would you do `SNAT` for a traffic coming from the local machine? For example let's say that there is PC with `eth1` facing LAN(IP address 10.10.10.1/24) and `eth0` facing Internet(IP address 198.51.100.1/24)- all the traffic going out from this machine to Internet will simply use 198.51.100.1 as a source IP address and no `SNAT` is needed. IMHO `SNAT` is needed only in case traffic flows through the PC and then it goes through the `PREROUTING`. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

As the chain names suggest, `PREROUTING` is done at first when a packet is received and is thus routed based on where it is going (destination).  After all other routing rules have been applied, the `POSTROUTING` chain will determine where it goes based on where it came from (source).

For example, on my server, incoming ports that are to be forwarded (NATed) are all defined in the `PREROUTING` chain as `DNAT`, and all packets that come from the NATed interfaces, go through the `POSTROUTING` chain as `SNAT`, and consequently (in this case), go through the filter `FORWARD` chain.

Answer (score 2):

[One else](https://pastebin.com/y4TJ3akM) nice schematic in ASCII that might help to figure out how does it work, it is handy for beginners to have it in console when working with iptables rules:

```
#
# (PACKET IN)->-[PREROUTING]->- ->----------->-[FORWARD]->------------>- ->-[POSTROUTING]->-(PACKET OUT)
#               -mangle        |               -mangle                  |   -mangle
#               -nat (dst)     |               -filter                  |   -nat (src)
#                              |                                        |
#                               ->-[INPUT]->-(APPLICATION)->-[OUTPUT]->-
#                                  -mangle                   -mangle
#                                  -filter                   -filter
#                                                            -nat (dst)
#
```

(* Edited, considering the comments below...)

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that [link-only answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) are discouraged, as the link may become invalid or the linked content change. Please edit your answer to include at least a summary of the linked explanation.

Answer (score 0):

When doing any packet manipulation in Linux, the usual path from chains perspective is PREROUTING been hit as first chain and POSTROUTING is the last chain in the packet path. There are many configurations which a router usually have which even includes some transformation like IPsec VPN tunnel selection for a particular flow. Usually with SNAT the intention is to send the packet with an address which can be reached by hosts connected in public network. Such changes are done to packet when it is about to leave the router, i.e. POSTROUTING level just before the OUTPUT to avoid any mixing of the IP Addresses. Similarly in the reverse direction first thing the router expects is to see the actual flow so that all the decisions as per the configurations can be applied as the packet traverses the stack. This can be only achieved if we do the DNAT at the earliest level which is PREROUTING.